# text binding through angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs

I need to get a string value into a directive's view, and while that should be straightforward, it's not working.

in the view calling the directive:
`<hc-component-blocker animation="/images/spinner_black_16.gif"></hc-component-blocker>`

the directive:

```
angular.module('xnuapp')
    .directive('hcComponentBlocker', function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'views/hccomponentblocker.html',
            priority: 1005,
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                animation: '@'
            },
            controller: 'ComponentBlockerCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'ComponentBlocker',
            bindToController: true
       };
});
```

directive's template:

```
<div class="component-blocker" ng-if="!ComponentBlocker.thisComponentIsLoaded">
    <img ng-src="{{ComponentBlocker.animation}}"/>
</div>
```

ComponentBlockerCtrl:

```
angular.module('xnuapp')
    .controller('ComponentBlockerCtrl', function ($scope, HC_EVENTS) {
        console.log(this.animation);
});
```

I get the expected string value in the console when I run this ("/images/spinner_black_16.gif").

but the image doesn't display. What gets rendered in the HTML is `<div class="component-blocker ng-scope" ng-if="!ComponentBlocker.thisComponentIsLoaded" animation="/images/spinner_black_16.gif"><img></div>`

What should I look for? I thought this was the model for getting that string value for `animation` into the controller and view. Why doesn't the view get the value of that property passed to it?

Comment: For ng-src, you don't use the {{ }}.  You would if you were doing src=.  Should be <img ng-src="ComponentBlocker.animation"/>

Comment: I get the same behavior when I change ng-src= to src=

Answer (score 0):

this was fixed by changing `replace` to `false`. I'm not entirely sure why that worked, but it did.